# Can we post to url when invoking firefox from python script

Tags: python, firefox

I have a python script and I am trying to login to some website.
Once I get the session Id, I want to post some values to a url.
Here I am invoking firefox using os.system(). I want firefox to post the values to the url and from there all the session should be maintained in firefox itself.

Can we make firefox to post values to a url when firefox is invoked from python script/ command line?

Or is there any other way to achieve this same effect?

Comment: You should look at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#introduction). It allows you to control browsers from Python. Do you actually need to run Firefox to do this?

Comment: What if the user prefers a different browser?

Comment: In order to transfer the session fo FF, you'll need an add-on that lets you set cookies inside FF. There's probably an add-on that lets you do this by hand, I don't know how you would do it by remote control from Python.

Comment: There is no need for cookies. The session is maintained in the session id in query string. I can get the session id from python script. Once I get this, I need to post some values to the url using firefox. From there on, firefox will be used for the rest of the session. This is for my own use only. I am the only user of this script. May be I should look into Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you two other ways.

First of all, the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. It will keep the session. I have successfully used this module to keep session, post forms, etc.

**EDIT** example requests code

```
payload = {'param' : 'value'}
session = requests.session()
session.get(url)
response = session.post(form_url, data=payload)
```

Second, I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but If you want to automate Firefox from Python, you may consider [Selenium + Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`webbrowser` module](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html).

> The script webbrowser can be used as a command-line interface for the module. It accepts an URL as the argument.